# C++ function pointers and callback functions

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm not a C++ guy and I'm having some trouble understanding how to pass a function pointer/callback function to a method. The callback is defined as follows

```
typedef HRESULT (CALLBACK *PFN_CREATE_XAMLOBJECT)(
    IXRDependencyObject *pExistingXRDO,
    UINT objectId
);
```

The method I am attempting to pass it too is defined as follows (all other params removed)

```
virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE RegisterXamlObject(
    __in    PFN_CREATE_XAMLOBJECT   pfXamlObjectCreation,
) = 0;
```

The function I have defined to pass on is as follows

```
HRESULT CreateFn(__in IXRDependencyObject *pExistingXRDO, UINT objectId)
{
    return S_OK;
}
```

I am attempting to pass the the function pointer as follows.

```
&MyClass::CreateFn
```

I get the following error

```
Error   3   error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'HRESULT (__cdecl MyClass::* )(IXRDependencyObject *,UINT)' to 'PFN_CREATE_XAMLOBJECT'
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: have you defined CreateFn as static?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems here.

First, a function pointer can not point to a member function, because a member function requires a `this` pointer to operate.  You must make the member function `static`, or make the pointer a member function pointer.

Second, the function pointer and the function must use the same calling convention.  The pointer uses `CALLBACK`, which is defined to `__stdcall`.

Here's a revised function:

```
static HRESULT CALLBACK CreateFn(IXRDependencyObject *pExistingXRDO,
                                 UINT objectId)
{
    return S_OK;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers folks. Super fast!

Answer (score 0):

you must pass a plain function, not a member function (a function which is a field of a class). They are distinct objects, in fact, the method takes a hidden additional argument, which is obviously the pointer to `this` (the object the method is called on). If you want to enclose the callback definition in a class anyway, make it a static method.

Answer (score 0):

A member function needs an object to be called on which you're not passing, while what you want is a normal function.

Use a static method in your class instead, that does not require an object pointer to be passed to it.